# What does "quality" mean in canon 1098?

Tags: catholicism, marriage, canon-law

I was wondering about the definition of "quality" in [canon 1098](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib4-cann998-1165_en.html#CHAPTER_IV.) of the Catholic Church's 1983 Code of Canon Law:

> [Can. 1098](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/latin/documents/cic_liberIV_la.html) A person contracts invalidly who enters into a marriage deceived by malice, perpetrated to obtain consent, concerning some quality (*qualitatem*) of the other partner which by its very nature can gravely disturb the partnership of conjugal life.

Would it be fair to say that a "quality" in the sense intended by this canon must be a stable characteristic present at the time of consent? This would mean that something that may have been defined as a quality at some point before marriage - tendency towards drug use, for instance - which later disappears from the person and is absent at the time of consent, is not a "quality" in the sense intended by this canon. Do I have that right?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Answer (score 1):

[*New Commentary on the* [1983] *Code of Canon Law*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8346) pp. 1307,8:

> (2) *The deceit must bear on a quality of the
> person "which by its very nature can gravely
> disturb the partnership of conjugal life."* A
> quality of a person is an inherent or distin­guishing characteristic or trait of a person. Iso­lated actions in the past are not normally con­sidered to be qualities. Thus, the fact that a
> man once smoked marijuana is not one of his
> qualities, but the fact that he was once incar­cerated for drug possession and, therefore, has
> a criminal record or that he is a recovering
> drug addict is one of his qualities.

> (3) *The quality must be present (or absent)
> at the time of consent.* The quality that is the
> object of the deceit cannot be one that is ex­pected or hoped for in the future. Thus, a
> woman who married a man who had led her to
> believe that he intended to enter law school,
> even though he had no such intention, cannot
> claim that her marriage was invalid because of
> the deceit. On the other hand, a woman who
> was led to believe that the man she was about
> to marry already was a lawyer or had been ac­cepted at a law school may have a basis for
> claiming that her marriage was invalid as a
> consequence of this deceit.

[*Exegetical Commentary on the* [1983] *Code of Canon Law*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8346) vol. III/2, p. 1298:

> the quality that is the object of the deception must
> refer to the other spouse. This means that the quality cannot be discon­nected with and be foreign to the choice of a spouse but must be intrinsic
> to the selection of a person as spouse.